# How to convert Datetime from (ddmmyyyy hh:mm:ss) to (ddmmmyyyy:00:00:00) [SAS]

Tags: sas, date-format

I need to convert hour, minutes and seconds to 00:00:00

I´ve tried a lot but i got nothing but the real time.

`data pr; dat=put(date()-1,yymmddn.); datsas=PUT(datetime(), datetime.); run;`

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a datetime value already?  If you want to remove the timepart from that datetime value you can just use subtraction.

```
midnight = datetime - timepart(datetime);
```

Or you could take the datepart and recreate a datetime value from it.

```
midnight = dhms(datepart(datetime),0,0,0);
```

Or you could use INTNX() function to transform to the start of the current DTDAY interval

```
midnight = intnx('dtday',datetime,0,'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `INTNX` function to advance a date time value to another date time value.

Example:

```
data _null_;
  now_dtm = datetime();
  now0_dtm = intnx ('dtday', now_dtm, 0);

  put now_dtm datetime19.;
  put now0_dtm datetime19.;
run;

----- Log -----
 10FEB2022:04:22:51
 10FEB2022:00:00:00
```